# Getting text from a URL and transforming before entry in array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, parsing

I'm getting this from web page:

```
channels = getting_channels.group()
```

)/AV1/AV2/AV3/AV4

and I want to put in array the next values: 
{"emite":"AV1"},{"emite":"AV2"},{"emite":"AV3"},{"emite":"AV4"}

¿Is it possible?

Comment: Is that a string or what data type it is?

Comment: And please, give it a try and post it if you face any issues..This is way you will be useful to your own good and help us solve and improve your code.

Comment: just for the record, i totally agree with Iron Fist; i am simply assuming you did try and failed for some reason..

Comment: I'm triying and failing 2 weeks ago... I'm near to get the result some times, but alwais need something more... In any case, i get the sugestions from the future questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes that the there is going to be a string before the first slash that is useless to you. The total number of slashes is irrelevant (they don't have to be 4)

```
astring = ')/AV1/AV2/AV3/AV4'

result = []
for i in range(1, len(astring.split('/'))):
   result.append({'emite':astring.split('/')[i]})

print(result) #prints [{'emite': 'AV1'}, {'emite': 'AV2'}, {'emite': 'AV3'}, {'emite': 'AV4'}]
```